# Get string attribute of a tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help to extract the inline image source (in this case #3) from the string below in javascript, then encapsulate and send it to php:

```
<img width="100" id="1" style="display: none;" src="http://col.stb00.s-msn.com/i/4E/5EA45CFEC5FF5726D86E65CEE815D.jpg">
<img width="100" id="2" style="display: none;" src="http://col.stb01.s-msn.com/i/36/59F78F98816E925C8A18FBCF013D5.jpg">
<img width="100" id="3" style="display: inline;" src="http://col.stb00.s-msn.com/i/6F/D11A5421FDC5E8C5CEA4D19BCC7A5.jpg">
<img width="100" id="4" style="display: none;" src="http://col.stb00.s-msn.com/i/88/B51A1462A325FF345AC442688F7A8.jpg">
<img width="100" id="5" style="display: none;" src="http://col.stb01.s-msn.com/i/39/8A811756CB49259F65032AB9F1D78.jpg">
```

Is there an easy way to do it please?
thanks

Comment: Is it a string or an actual element?

Comment: Are you interested in jQuery solutions?

Comment: Thanks, I retrieve the string by:

    str1=document.getElementById("images").innerHTML

but I'm not very good at javascript!

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i]["style"]["display"] === "inline") {
        console.log(imgs[i]["src"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use the shorter object syntax? `imgs[i].style.display`

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Use DOM:

```
function getSrc(id)
{
    var src = document.getElementById(id).src;
}
```

The variable `src` will hold the value of the `src` attribute in your tag. Do this for all of the tags that need their `src` elements extracted. You will probably need to use AJAX to pass this to PHP.

Comment: Note that he is looking for the `src` of the `display: inline` img.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst have now put it in a function. Happy?

Comment: Did you even read his question? He doesn't know the ID of the image with the display inline property. Making it a function doesn't make a difference from what you originally had.